# Javascript Custom Variable Syntax instead of var use $

Tags: javascript, html, variables, syntax

I am making a javascript library and wanted to make a custom variable syntax so instead of using var use $ like php. To be clear I DO NOT want to use PHP. I am making a special library for public use.

I honestly don't care if you give me a function I just really need to use $ instead of var please I really need this.

```js
var x = 10; // Normal JavaScript variable

$x = 10; // Custom Variable Syntax which is what I would like
```

Comment: I'm extremely curious as to why you want it so badly? JS isn't customizable.

Comment: What is the question?  `$` is a legal character in any Javascript variable name.  So, you can define a variable like `var $x = 10`, but you can't replace the need for `var` or `let` to declare locally scoped variables.  Javascript is not customizable in that fashion (thank goodness).

Comment: If you explain the real overall problem you're trying to solve (which would include why you're trying to do this) instead of just asking for this specific solution to whatever the problem is, then we might be able to help better.

Comment: So, apparently (from some of your comments), you're trying to use Javascript, but make it accept some PHP type syntax.  Can't do that at all.  The Javascript syntax in an existing implementation is not customizable and it is fully described in a specification.  You could, of course, build your language interpreter that started with a Javascript implementation and then add your own syntax into it, but you could only run that code in your engine, not in any regular Javascript engine.

Comment: so my website if i was to do that would not be able to run the language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript provides no means to extend the language in this way.

If you want to invent your own syntax, you'll need to design your own programming language and transpile it to JavaScript (as CoffeeScript does, for example).

(NB: `$x` is a valid identifier in JavaScript, you just can't cause any variable name starting with a `$` to be inferred (by JS) as being a locally scoped variable when you assign something to it. `$x = 10;` would therefore throw an error (or create a global if you weren't using strict mode)).

Comment: So there is no possible way not even with a JavaScript library?

Comment: A library is still just JavaScript.

Comment: Great welp my php2js library won't be look like php now :(

Comment: Why would you *want* JS to look like PHP? JS is so much prettier...

Comment: @nnnnnn because i am making a client version of php so I can use it offline and because the idea is to have it look like php so it is like php

Comment: Same, I am trying to beautify and simplify javascript as well :(

Who likes looking at those millions of lines of JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Syntax is not customization and keywords can not be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Language is language, you can't jump over it's rules. But you can look around, use it's native possibilities.

As I know- there is no option to write
    $x = 10;
in javascript. Just no.
But you can dance like jQuery (`$` as alias of `window.jQuery`- that's not solution, but just first think about similar actions).

Can you tell more about that problem? Why do you need that? Maybe there's simpler way?

Comment: Well i am making a php to javascript library and I am trying to make it resemble as close as possible to php and use $ instead of var would be awesome and extremely great thing to have in the library